# How to use UnityPlayer in multiple activities

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my android application having 2 activities where I need to show Camera (Live) mode and 3D object (offline) mode in first activity and other activity just showing 3D objects. So basically I want to use unity player in both of these activities. Its working fine in first activity but I am facing problem while using unity player in other activity. Any help or guidance on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I may have an idea, but your explanation are not enougth, What don't you know to do? Showing 3D models? But you say you can do so when camera is on, so why not whithout camera?

Comment: Its not like I am able to show without camera, its working fine in first activity but unityplayer is not working in 2nd activity.

Comment: What do ou call an activity?

Comment: I am not getting exactly what you want to ask? I am calling my second activity which contains unity player instance from first activity.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I dd not understand what you meant. So, I'm not able to help you, but: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/780406/androidunity-launching-activity-from-unity-activit.html